# Swift move drawn line's end point based on nearest touch & move

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, cgcontext

I am following this [useful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330676/how-to-detect-angle-on-touchbegan-and-touchmoved-actions-in-ios-swift) to make line which movable at both end.

According to my requirements:

1. When I do touch near in respect of start point of drawn line, starting point should move and ending point shouldn't move.
2. Same thing should be happened in respect of ending point.

Please let me know if anybody has a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: I am just able to move end point, not starting point of drawn line.

Comment: It sounds like you first need to calculate the distance of both points using the initial position of `touchesBegan`, and the position of the point. Then using whichever is lower, move that point. Could you show us some code to see what's happening?

Comment: @MattLeFleur Yes, it is now working , i did as you said. Thanks

Comment: one more thing , what if i have drawn one more line , then same thing  will be needed to do with that ?

Comment: Similar, you'd just have to make sure that when you are working out the distances you know which line that each point is referring to, so that you move the right line

Comment: @MattLeFleur i did that same and really it is working

Comment: I just have one more thing that i want to join this two lines and respect of this join want to get angle, then which method is suitable?

Comment: Hay is my question votable ?

Comment: This might sound a bit complex: You'll want the inverse cosine of the dot product of the normalised vectors of each line. [Check this out](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/vectors/angleBetween/)

Comment: @Shivam Sharma M Have you found the solution? If yes Please explain.